# Why has my link an infinite width?

Tags: css, xml

I am making something with xml but the links have an infinite width.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jg0v6dv/1/) (hover over the link discription and you will see it)

**My xml link code**

the `<l>` tag is the link.

```
<b>link 1</b><l href="#">description</l>
```

**css code**

```
l{
  color:#222;
  font-size:18;
  font-style: italic;
  display:block;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:auto;
}
l:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:blue;
}
```

When I specify a `width` like 200px it works but when I put it to auto it doesn't so can somebody help me with solving this problem?

I have Jquery working on the page so if I need to solve the problem with Jquery that is no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens due to

```
Display: block;
```

in CSS

**Edit:**

If you wish to do all by CSS itself use this (just in-case if you don't want to use 
 in HTML)

```
l{
    color:#222;
    font-size:18;
    font-style: italic;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
}
l:before, l:after{
    display:block;
    content:" ";
}
```

Comment: Simply remove display:block from CSS and add <br /> in html after <l> tags. That should do...

Comment: Solved. Thanks for helping. I have only one question: Why is `display:block;` causing this problem?

Comment: Providing "Display: block ", is you are trying to tell the browser to render it as block that uses the maximum width. That is the nature of the "block", whereas "inline-block" tries to use as less width as possible. Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you pls explain your edit? I don't understand the `:before` and `:after` part

Comment: using ":before" and ":after" you will be able to add content, edit styles of that content added through CSS. I have added a space and given full width (block), thus pushing the following content to next line, forcing a line break.

Comment: To know more about ":before" and ":after" refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed if you take out

```
display:block;
```

and add a

```
<br/>
```

after your link markup

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this: CSS: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jg0v6dv/13/)**

```
l{
    color:#222;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style: italic; 
    transition:all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<b>link 1</b><l href="#">description</l>
        <br></br>
        <b>link 2</b> <l href="#">description</l>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are many ways to deal with this problem.

**Html solution:** [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jg0v6dv/15/)

```
//........
<link>
        <table>
            <tr><td><b>link 1</b><l href="#">description</l></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>link 2</b> <l href="#">description</l></td></tr>
        </table>
</link>
//.....
```

**Css solution:** [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jg0v6dv/14/)

```
l {
   //........
   display:table;
   //.......
}
```

Comment: @Vinc199789 , I think the second solution is the easiest one `display:table;`, what do you think??

Comment: The second one works good but Somebody else already gave me some css code and that works but thansk for your suggestion, more solutions are always good. The first one is not a good solution because I never use table and I only want to use xml.

Comment: `I never use table and I only want to use xml`, can you explain it? @Vinc199789

Comment: Like you can see in the question it is an xml file I am using so I want to use as less as possible html code and your table was html. And I just don't like table. I am good enough to make my own table system for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Block level elements take up the width of the container. Set them to inline-block and use a list element to contain the list items